Having trouble with decimal places on output for my dashboard
I’m a beginner at coding and trying to build a dashboard in React, but I’m having trouble limiting the decimal places for some values. Specifically, I have a column for estimated APY, which I want to show with 2 decimal places, like 8.32%.
However, what I’m seeing instead is a really large number with many decimals, like 2.2165511827505747e+24%.
I tried using .toFixed(2) in my code, but it doesn’t seem to be working as expected. I suspect that I might be missing something important or maybe I'm using it in the wrong context.
Here’s a bit of the code I’m working with:
javascript
const calculateEstimatedAPY = (profit, signalDate) => { if (profit === 0 || !signalDate) return 0; const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000; const timeElapsed = currentTime - signalDate; const yearsElapsed = timeElapsed / (365 * 24 * 60 * 60); return ((profit / yearsElapsed) * 100).toFixed(2); };

Even with .toFixed(2), the APY shows up with too many digits. Could it be that I need to format it again at the point where it's displayed? How should I properly format this in React to make sure only 2 decimal places are shown throughout my UI?
Any help or advice would be much appreciated! I’m still getting used to all of this, so thanks in advance for your patience and support.
     "use client";

import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react';
import { fetchCuratorSignals, fetchTimestamps } from './lib/graphql-client';

// Utility function for formatting to two decimal places
const formatToTwoDecimals = (value: number): number => parseFloat(value.toFixed(2));

// Define possible keys for sorting
type SortableKeys =
  | 'signalledTokens'
  | 'unsignalledTokens'
  | 'signal'
  | 'subgraph.metadata.displayName'
  | 'profit'
  | 'estimatedAPY'
  | 'lastSignalChange'
  | 'lastNameSignalChange';

// Format numbers to be more readable (convert wei to ether and format)
const formatNumber = (
  value: string | number | null | undefined,
  decimals: number = 2,
) => {
  if (value === null || value === undefined) return 'N/A';
  const num = typeof value === 'string' ? parseFloat(value) : value;
  const ethValue = num / 1e18; // Assume values are in wei and convert to Ether
  if (ethValue >= 1e9) return (ethValue / 1e9).toFixed(decimals) + 'B';
  if (ethValue >= 1e6) return (ethValue / 1e6).toFixed(decimals) + 'M';
  if (ethValue >= 1e3) return (ethValue / 1e3).toFixed(decimals) + 'K';
  return ethValue.toFixed(decimals);
};

// Profit calculation that accounts for unsignaled tokens and current value
const calculateProfit = (
  signalledTokens: string,
  unsignalledTokens: string | undefined,
  currentValue: number | null,
) => {
  const signalledInWei = parseFloat(signalledTokens || '0');
  const unsignalledInWei = unsignalledTokens ? parseFloat(unsignalledTokens) : 0;

  if (unsignalledInWei > 0 && currentValue !== null) {
    return unsignalledInWei + currentValue - signalledInWei;
  }

  if (unsignalledInWei > 0) {
    return unsignalledInWei - signalledInWei;
  }

  if (currentValue !== null) {
    return currentValue - signalledInWei;
  }

  return 0;
};

// Calculate the current value of signals
const calculateCurrentValue = (pricePerShare: string, signal: string) => {
  const price = parseFloat(pricePerShare || '0');
  const signalValue = parseFloat(signal || '0');
  return price * signalValue;
};

// Calculate estimated APY based on signal date
const calculateEstimatedAPY = (
  profit: number,
  signalDate: number | undefined
): number => {
  if (profit === 0 || !signalDate) return 0;

  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;
  const timeElapsed = currentTime - signalDate;
  const yearsElapsed = timeElapsed / (365 * 24 * 60 * 60);

  return parseFloat(((profit / yearsElapsed) * 100).toFixed(2));
};

const Dashboard = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<{
    id: string;
    nameSignals: {
      signalledTokens: string;
      unsignalledTokens: string;
      signal: string;
      subgraph: {
        id: string;
        metadata: { displayName: string };
        currentVersion: {
          subgraphDeployment: {
            pricePerShare: string;
            signalAmount: string;
          };
        };
      };
      lastNameSignalChange?: number;
    }[];
    signals: {
      signalledTokens: string;
      unsignalledTokens: string;
      signal: string;
      subgraphDeployment: {
        id: string;
        pricePerShare: string;
        versions: {
          metadata: { label: string };
          subgraph: {
            metadata: { displayName: string };
          };
        }[];
      };
      lastSignalChange?: number;
    }[];
    combinedSignalCount: number;
    nameSignalTransactions: {
      id: string;
      nameSignal: string;
      timestamp: number;
    }[];
  } | null>(null);

  const [totalProfit, setTotalProfit] = useState<number>(0);
  const [priorTotalProfit, setPriorTotalProfit] = useState<number>(0);
  const [totalEstimatedAPY, setTotalEstimatedAPY] = useState<string>('0.00');
  const [priorTotalEstimatedAPY, setPriorTotalEstimatedAPY] = useState<string>('0.00');
  const [totalSignalledSubgraphs, setTotalSignalledSubgraphs] = useState<number>(0);
  const [activeSignalCount, setActiveSignalCount] = useState<number>(0);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState<string>(''); // Filter by subgraph name
  const [walletFilter, setWalletFilter] = useState<string>(''); // Filter by wallet
  const [showPriorSignals, setShowPriorSignals] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [showActiveSignalsOnly, setShowActiveSignalsOnly] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const handleFetch = async () => {
    if (!walletFilter) return;

    try {
      const lowercasedWallet = walletFilter.toLowerCase();
      console.log('Fetching data for wallet:', lowercasedWallet);

      const fetchedData = await fetchCuratorSignals(lowercasedWallet);
      console.log('Fetched Data:', fetchedData);

      if (fetchedData && fetchedData.curator) {
        let runningTotalProfit = 0;
        let priorRunningTotalProfit = 0;
        let runningTotalSignalledTokens = 0;
        let priorRunningTotalSignalledTokens = 0;
        let subgraphCount = 0;
        let activeCount = 0;

        const timestampsData = await fetchTimestamps(lowercasedWallet);
        console.log('Fetched Timestamps Data:', timestampsData);

        // Calculate current signals profit and other data
        fetchedData.curator.nameSignals.forEach((signalData) => {
          const { signal } = signalData;
          const currentVersion = signalData.subgraph.currentVersion;
          const pricePerShare = (currentVersion?.subgraphDeployment as { pricePerShare: string })?.pricePerShare ?? '0';
          const currentValue = pricePerShare
            ? calculateCurrentValue(pricePerShare, signal)
            : null;

          const profit = calculateProfit(
            signalData.signalledTokens,
            signalData.unsignalledTokens,
            currentValue
          );

          runningTotalProfit += profit;
          runningTotalSignalledTokens += parseFloat(signalData.signalledTokens || '0');

          if (parseFloat(signalData.signalledTokens) > 0) {
            subgraphCount += 1;
            if (currentValue !== null && currentValue > 0) {
              activeCount += 1;
            }
          }

          // Update timestamps for current signals
          const matchingTimestamp = timestampsData?.nsignalMintedEvents.find(
            (t: any) => t.subgraph.id === signalData.subgraph.id
          );
          if (matchingTimestamp) {
            signalData.lastNameSignalChange = matchingTimestamp.timestamp;
          }
        });

        // Calculate prior signals profit with current value included
        fetchedData.curator.signals.forEach((signalData) => {
          const { signal } = signalData;
          const pricePerShare = signalData.subgraphDeployment?.pricePerShare ?? '0';
          const currentValue = pricePerShare
            ? calculateCurrentValue(pricePerShare, signal)
            : null;

          const profit = calculateProfit(
            signalData.signalledTokens,
            signalData.unsignalledTokens,
            currentValue
          );

          priorRunningTotalProfit += profit;
          priorRunningTotalSignalledTokens += parseFloat(signalData.signalledTokens || '0');

          // Update timestamps for prior signals
          const matchingTimestamp = timestampsData?.signalBurnedEvents.find(
            (t: any) => t.deployment.id === signalData.subgraphDeployment.id
          );
          if (matchingTimestamp) {
            signalData.lastSignalChange = matchingTimestamp.timestamp;
          }

          const nsignalMatchingTimestamp = timestampsData?.nsignalBurnedEvents.find(
            (t: any) => t.subgraph.id === signalData.subgraphDeployment.id
          );
          if (nsignalMatchingTimestamp) {
            signalData.lastSignalChange = nsignalMatchingTimestamp.timestamp;
          }
        });

        setTotalProfit(runningTotalProfit);
        setPriorTotalProfit(priorRunningTotalProfit);
        setTotalEstimatedAPY(runningTotalProfit > 0 ? calculateEstimatedAPY(runningTotalProfit, fetchedData.curator.nameSignals[0]?.lastNameSignalChange).toFixed(2) : '0.00');
        setPriorTotalEstimatedAPY(priorRunningTotalProfit > 0 ? calculateEstimatedAPY(priorRunningTotalProfit, fetchedData.curator.signals[0]?.lastSignalChange).toFixed(2) : '0.00');
        setTotalSignalledSubgraphs(subgraphCount);
        setActiveSignalCount(fetchedData.curator.combinedSignalCount);
        setData({
          ...fetchedData.curator,
          nameSignals: fetchedData.curator.nameSignals.map((signal) => ({
            ...signal,
            subgraph: {
              ...signal.subgraph,
              currentVersion: {
                ...signal.subgraph.currentVersion,
                subgraphDeployment: {
                  pricePerShare: (signal.subgraph.currentVersion.subgraphDeployment as { pricePerShare: string })?.pricePerShare || '0',
                  signalAmount: (signal.subgraph.currentVersion.subgraphDeployment as { signalAmount: string })?.signalAmount || '0',
                },
              },
            },
          })),
          nameSignalTransactions: fetchedData.nameSignalTransactions ?? [],
        });
      } else {
        console.error('No curator data found for wallet:', lowercasedWallet);
        throw new Error('No curator data found.');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error fetching curator signals:', err);
    }
  };

  // Additional components, rendering logic, and sorting fixes below...
  // Render functions like `renderSignalTableRows()` were also fixed to ensure consistent formatting.
  

  // Filter by subgraph name and active status
  const filteredData = useMemo(() => {
    if (!data) return [];

    return data.nameSignals.filter((signalData) => {
      const matchesFilter = signalData.subgraph.metadata.displayName
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(filter.toLowerCase());
      // Use shares (signal value) to determine if it's active
      const shares = parseFloat(signalData.signal || '0'); // Signal represents shares here
      const unsignalledTokens = parseFloat(signalData.unsignalledTokens || '0');
      const isActive =
        !showActiveSignalsOnly || (shares > 0.01 && unsignalledTokens < shares * 0.99);

      return matchesFilter && isActive;
    });
  }, [data, filter, showActiveSignalsOnly]);

  const filteredPriorData = useMemo(() => {
    if (!data) return [];

    return data.signals.filter((signalData) => {
      const matchesFilter = signalData.subgraphDeployment.versions?.[0]?.subgraph?.metadata?.displayName
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(filter.toLowerCase());
      const shares = parseFloat(signalData.signal || '0');
      const unsignalledTokens = parseFloat(signalData.unsignalledTokens || '0');
      const isActive =
        !showActiveSignalsOnly || (shares > 0.01 && unsignalledTokens < shares * 0.99);

      return matchesFilter && isActive;
    });
  }, [data, filter, showActiveSignalsOnly]);

  // Sort current and prior signals by profit descending
  const sortedCurrentSignals = useMemo(() => {
    return filteredData.sort((a, b) => {
      const profitA = calculateProfit(
        a.signalledTokens,
        a.unsignalledTokens,
        a.subgraph.currentVersion.subgraphDeployment.pricePerShare
          ? calculateCurrentValue(
              a.subgraph.currentVersion.subgraphDeployment.pricePerShare,
              a.signal,
            )
          : null,
      );

      const profitB = calculateProfit(
        b.signalledTokens,
        b.unsignalledTokens,
        b.subgraph.currentVersion.subgraphDeployment.pricePerShare
          ? calculateCurrentValue(
              b.subgraph.currentVersion.subgraphDeployment.pricePerShare,
              b.signal,
            )
          : null,
      );

      return (profitB ?? 0) - (profitA ?? 0);
    });
  }, [filteredData]);

  const sortedPriorSignals = useMemo(() => {
    return filteredPriorData.sort((a, b) => {
      const profitA = calculateProfit(
        a.signalledTokens,
        a.unsignalledTokens,
        a.subgraphDeployment.pricePerShare
          ? calculateCurrentValue(a.subgraphDeployment.pricePerShare, a.signal)
          : null,
      );

      const profitB = calculateProfit(
        b.signalledTokens,
        b.unsignalledTokens,
        b.subgraphDeployment.pricePerShare
          ? calculateCurrentValue(b.subgraphDeployment.pricePerShare, b.signal)
          : null,
      );

      return (profitB ?? 0) - (profitA ?? 0);
    });
  }, [filteredPriorData]);

  const renderSignalTableRows = (
    signalsData: unknown[], // Changed to 'unknown' to avoid 'any' type
    isPrior: boolean = false,
  ) => {
    return signalsData.map((signalData: any, index) => {
      const subgraphName = isPrior
        ? `${signalData.subgraphDeployment?.versions?.[0]?.subgraph?.metadata?.displayName || 'Unknown Subgraph'} (${signalData.subgraphDeployment?.versions?.[0]?.metadata?.label || 'Unknown Version'})`
        : signalData.subgraph?.metadata?.displayName || 'Unknown Subgraph';
  
      const signalValue = signalData.signal
        ? parseFloat(signalData.signal) / 1e18
        : 0;
  
      const signalledTokens = signalData.signalledTokens
        ? parseFloat(signalData.signalledTokens) / 1e18
        : 0;
  
      const unsignalledTokens = signalData.unsignalledTokens
        ? parseFloat(signalData.unsignalledTokens) / 1e18
        : 0;
  
      const currentValueRaw = isPrior
        ? signalData.subgraphDeployment.pricePerShare
          ? calculateCurrentValue(signalData.subgraphDeployment.pricePerShare, signalData.signal)
          : null
        : signalData.subgraph?.currentVersion?.subgraphDeployment?.pricePerShare
        ? calculateCurrentValue(
            signalData.subgraph.currentVersion.subgraphDeployment.pricePerShare,
            signalData.signal,
          )
        : null;
  
      const currentValue = currentValueRaw ? currentValueRaw / 1e18 : null;
  
      const profitRaw = calculateProfit(
        signalData.signalledTokens,
        signalData.unsignalledTokens,
        currentValueRaw,
      );
  
      const profit = profitRaw ? profitRaw / 1e18 : 0;
  
      const estimatedAPY = calculateEstimatedAPY(
        profitRaw,
        isPrior ? signalData.lastSignalChange : signalData.lastNameSignalChange
      ).toFixed(2);
  
      const lastChangeTime = isPrior
        ? signalData.lastSignalChange
          ? new Date(signalData.lastSignalChange * 1000).toLocaleString()
          : 'N/A'
        : signalData.lastNameSignalChange
        ? new Date(signalData.lastNameSignalChange * 1000).toLocaleString()
        : 'N/A';
  
      return (
        <tr key={index} style={{ textAlign: 'right', borderBottom: '1px solid #ccc' }}>
          <td style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}>{index + 1}. {subgraphName}</td>
          <td>{signalledTokens.toFixed(2)}</td>
          <td>{lastChangeTime}</td> {/* Display last signal change time */}
          <td>{unsignalledTokens.toFixed(2)}</td>
          <td>{signalValue.toFixed(2)}</td> {/* Display shares */}
          <td>{currentValue !== null ? currentValue.toFixed(2) : 'N/A'}</td>
          <td style={{ color: profit >= 0 ? 'green' : 'red' }}>
            {profit !== null ? profit.toFixed(2) : 'N/A'}
          </td>
          <td style={{ color: parseFloat(estimatedAPY) >= 0 ? 'green' : 'red' }}>
          {parseFloat(estimatedAPY).toFixed(2)}% {/* Ensure 2 decimal places */}
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  };
  
  
  // Trigger handleFetch when the user presses Enter
  const handleKeyPress = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      handleFetch();
    }
  };

  return (
  <div style={{ padding: '20px', color: '#fff', backgroundColor: '#1e1e1e', position: 'relative' }}>
    <div className="glowing-logo-container">
      <div className="glowing-effect">
        <img
          src="https://graphtronauts.app/assets/logo-white-B7t0qwEV.svg"
          alt="Logo"
          className="glowing-logo"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1 className="dashboard-title">Graphtronauts</h1>
    <style jsx>{`
      .glowing-logo-container {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        left: 20px;
      }

      .glowing-effect {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(63, 94, 251, 0.4) 0%, rgba(252, 70, 107, 0.6) 100%);
        padding: 20px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(63, 94, 251, 0.8), 0 0 40px rgba(252, 70, 107, 0.8);
      }

      .glowing-logo {
        position: relative;
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        z-index: 1;
      }

      .dashboard-title {
        position: absolute;
        top: 110px;
        left: 20px;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
      }
    `}</style>
    <div style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '20px', right: '20px', textAlign: 'right' }}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter your wallet or ENS name"
        value={walletFilter}
        onChange={(e) => setWalletFilter(e.target.value)}
        onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
        style={{
          padding: '10px',
          borderRadius: '5px',
          border: '1px solid #ccc',
          color: '#000',
          width: '300px',
        }}
      />
      <button
        onClick={handleFetch}
        style={{
          padding: '10px 20px',
          backgroundColor: '#007bff',
          color: '#fff',
          border: 'none',
          marginLeft: '10px'
        }}
      >
        Fetch Data
      </button>
    </div>

    <div style={{ marginBottom: '20px', textAlign: 'center' }}>
      <h2>Subgraph Curation Dashboard</h2>
      <p>
        <strong>Total Profit (Current Signals):</strong>{' '}
        <span style={{ color: totalProfit >= 0 ? 'green' : 'red' }}>
          {formatNumber(totalProfit)}
        </span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <strong>Total Profit (Prior Signals):</strong>{' '}
        <span style={{ color: priorTotalProfit >= 0 ? 'green' : 'red' }}>
          {formatNumber(priorTotalProfit)}
        </span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <strong>Estimated APY (Current Signals):</strong>{' '}
        <span style={{ color: Number (totalEstimatedAPY) >= 0 ? 'green' : 'red' }}>
          {Number (totalEstimatedAPY).toFixed(2)}%
        </span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <strong>Estimated APY (Prior Signals):</strong>{' '}
        <span style={{ color: Number (priorTotalEstimatedAPY) >= 0 ? 'green' : 'red' }}>
          {Number (priorTotalEstimatedAPY).toFixed(2)}%
        </span>
      </p>
      <p>
        <strong>Signal Count on Current Subgraphs:</strong> {totalSignalledSubgraphs}
      </p>
      <p>
        <strong>Total Signal Count:</strong> {activeSignalCount}
      </p>
    </div>

    {/* Filter by Subgraph Name */}
    <div style={{ marginBottom: '20px', textAlign: 'center' }}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Filter subgraphs by name"
        value={filter}
        onChange={(e) => setFilter(e.target.value)}
        style={{
          padding: '10px',
          borderRadius: '5px',
          border: '1px solid #ccc',
          color: '#000',
          width: '300px',
        }}
      />
      <label style={{ marginLeft: '20px' }}>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={showActiveSignalsOnly}
          onChange={() => setShowActiveSignalsOnly(!showActiveSignalsOnly)}
          style={{ marginRight: '10px' }}
        />
        Show Active Signals Only
      </label>
    </div>

    {/* Display current signals */}
    <div>
      <h3>Current Signals</h3>
      <table style={{ width: '100%', borderCollapse: 'collapse' }}>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}>Subgraph Name</th>
            <th style={{ textAlign: 'right' }}>Signalled Tokens</th>
            <th style={{ textAlign: 'right' }}>Signal Date</th> {/* Added column for creation date */}
            <th style={{ textAlign: 'right' }}>Unsignalled Tokens</th>
            <th style={{ textAlign: 'right' }}>Shares</th>
            <th style={{ textAlign: 'right' }}>Current Value</th>
            <th style={{ textAlign: 'right' }}>Profit</th>
            <th style={{ textAlign: 'right' }}>Estimated APY</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{renderSignalTableRows(sortedCurrentSignals || [], false)}</tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    {/* Display prior signals with a gap and collapsible feature */}
    <div style={{ marginTop: '40px', textAlign: 'center' }}>
      <button
        onClick={() => setShowPriorSignals(!showPriorSignals)}
        style={{
          padding: '10px 20px',
          backgroundColor: '#28a745',
          color: '#fff',
          border: 'none',
          marginBottom: '20px',
        }}
      >
        {showPriorSignals ? 'Hide Prior Signals' : 'Show Prior Signals'}
      </button>
    </div>
    {showPriorSignals && (
      <div style={{ marginTop: '20px' }}>
        <h3>Prior Signals</h3>
        <table style={{ width: '100%', borderCollapse: 'collapse' }}>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}>Subgraph Name</th>
              <th style={{ textAlign: 'right' }}>Signalled Tokens</th>
              <th style={{ textAlign: 'right' }}>Signal Date</th>
              <th style={{ textAlign: 'right' }}>Unsignalled Tokens</th>
              <th style={{ textAlign: 'right' }}>Shares</th>
              <th style={{ textAlign: 'right' }}>Current Value</th>
              <th style={{ textAlign: 'right' }}>Profit</th>
              <th style={{ textAlign: 'right' }}>Estimated APY</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{renderSignalTableRows(sortedPriorSignals || [], true)}</tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;

I tried to add a function
// Utility function for formatting to two decimal places
const formatToTwoDecimals = (value: number): number => parseFloat(value.toFixed(2));

I also tried to put formatToTwoDecimals on places displaying the APY.
`

.toFixed(2) should work if the number is already in a standard numerical format, but the e+24 notation you’re seeing suggests the number might be extremely large or formatted as scientific notation.
Have you tried this: Number(2.2165511827505747e+24).toFixed(2);
